# Insert templated class in std::map with construction at insertion

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, dictionary, std

I am trying to insert an instance of a templated class that does not have a copy constructor into a map. The code below does not work, because at the `emplace` function the compiler wants to call the copy constructor. I do not understand why, because I understood from the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace#Example) that emplace does not move or copy:

> Careful use of emplace allows the new element to be constructed while
>   avoiding unnecessary copy or move operations.

This is my code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<typename T> class Class_a
{
    public:
        Class_a(T t1, T t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
        ~Class_a() {}
        Class_a(const Class_a&) = delete;
        Class_a& operator=(const Class_a&) = delete;
        Class_a(Class_a&&) = delete;
    private:
        const T t1_;
        const T t2_;
};

template<typename T>
using Class_a_map = std::map<std::string, Class_a<T>>;

int main()
{
    Class_a_map<double> class_a_map;
    std::string name = "test";
    double number1 = 42;
    double number2 = 43;
    class_a_map.emplace(name, Class_a<double>(number1, number2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why make the class non-movable? If it was movable but non-copyable this would have worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::piecewise_construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct) and [`std::forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) to create your objects in place.

```
class_a_map.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct, 
    std::forward_as_tuple(name),
    std::forward_as_tuple(number1, number2)
);
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cCVpv9rFoWwIkzBe)

---

`std::map::emplace` perfectly forwards a bunch of arguments to the underlying `std::pair` used for key/value storage. [`std::pair::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) has an overload that takes an [`std::piecewise_construct_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct_t) as its first argument and then two `std::tuple` instances: the first one will be used to construct `.first` in place, the second one will be used to construct `.second` in place.

From cppreference, regarding `std::pair`'s piecewise constructor:

> Forwards the elements of `first_args` to the constructor of `first` and forwards the elements of `second_args` to the constructor of `second`. This is the only non-default constructor that can be used to create a pair of non-copyable non-movable types.

Comment: In this particular case, `tie` is shorter.